# Android Studio how to get id from push of Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've done this push:

```
 mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 mDatabaseReference.child(TipoAnuncio).push().setValue(fichaPet);
```

(Where fichaPet is a ad's class which is pushed in other object from firebase database)

My BBDD:

[Users Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5AgP.jpg)

I wanna get push's ID to write inside Ads from Users of FirebaseDatabase, and do something like this:

```
 mDatabaseReference.child("Usuarios").child(userId).child("Ads").push().setValue(mDatabaseReference.child("Usuarios").child(userId).child("Ads").push().getKey());
```

but it doesn't get previously ID from previously ad published.
Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tipoAnuncioRef = mDatabaseReference.child(TipoAnuncio);
String key = tipoAnuncioRef.push().getKey(); //This is the value of your key
tipoAnuncioRef.child(key).setValue(fichaPet);
```

If you are using the `push()` methid again, a new id will be generated and there is no need for that.